# Refused to connect error in trustpilot for other website in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, api, magento2.3.1, magento2.4.2

I have two websites in my magento admin and I need to add trust boxes in the pages using trust pilot - trust boxes. It is working fine for one website, but when load other website url in the trustpilot - trustbox I getting "***refused to connect error***" .

How can I load my other website url in trustbox without getting this error. And what this error means ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it could be a [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) error, basically these allow you to prevent *potentially* malicious 3rd party resources being loaded on your store.

Check your `app/etc/config.php` file and look for `'Magento_Csp' => 1,`. If this is present you have CSP enabled.
Are you using the official TrustPilot plugin? If so you need to be using version 2.6.562 or later (This was when the [csp_whitelist.xml](https://github.com/trustpilot/plugin-magento2/commit/622339b9d487cee7e82f6e1d57a58ed577230070) file was introduced).

If you are not using the official TrustPilot module, but are including the trustbox as part of your theme, and you do have CSP enabled you will need to add some custom policies. Adobe have documentation [here](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/) explaining how to do so depending on your requirements.

*If this is the correct answer please mark it "accepted" as it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find the answer.*